# Is There a Better Way To Filter An Array With Multiple Conditions

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filtering

I am using a dropdown menu help filter an array and then place the data from the array back into a collectionView but, when I attempt to attempt to run the function that should sort and reload the collectionView, the screen goes blank.

I've tried to make set a baseline and then filter the array.

```
extension RestaurantDetails: menuViewDelegate {

    func didChangeMealSize(mealSizeText: String) {
        self.mealSize = mealSizeText
        print("Usage", self.mealSize)
    }

    func didChangeDrink(drinkName: String) {
        self.drink = drinkName
        print("drink", self.drink)
    }

    func didChangeProductType(productType: String) {
        self.productFilter = productType
        print("Filter", self.productFilter)
    }

    func didchangeSwitch(FriesSwitch: UISwitch) {

         if FriesSwitch.isOn == true {
            self.FriesOnly = true
            print("FRIES Only")
         } else {
            self.FriesOnly = false
            print("Drink & FRIES")
         }   

    func didendSelection(button: UIButton) {

        print("ran Here")

        if (SegmentType == "All" && FriesSwitch == false && mealSize == RestaurantDetails.allProductIdentifier && productFilter == RestaurantDetails.allProductIdentifier && price == 0.0) {
            filteredProducts = products
        } else {
            filteredProducts = products.filter { ($0.usage?.lowercased() ?? "") == bestFor}
        }
        productCollection.reloadData()
    }
```

I want to filter by selected: Meal Size, Drink, and With Or Without Fries. When didendSelection is run, All the properties of the selected variables print but, the collectionView comes back empty.

Comment: what is array which you use as  `dataSource` for your CollectionView?

Comment: its an array called: products

Comment: Then you can use `filteredProducts` instead, right?

Comment: Yes. After I load the data into self.products.append(*data*). I have filterProducts inherits from products (filterProducts: [Product]()